# How Many Touch Points Does Windows 7 Multi-Touch Support?

Tags: windows-7, multi-touch

As above. I think I heard it supports either a very high number (e.g. 5000) or unlimited - obviously restricted to the device.

Comment: I don't think I've seen this documented anywhere. Why, are you concerned that you won't have enough?

Comment: Also couldn't find any documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd562197%28VS.85%29.aspx)- maybe you're better of asking in the official MS forums (social.microsoft.com/forums)

Comment: It was mentioned on one of the developer pod casts I saw over the weekend. It's just a general query that we are debating in the office. Totally trivial and unrelated to any work.

Answer (score 2):

The Microsoft Surface v2.0 Hardware + Software platform was introduced in early January at CES. During the demo, they demonstrated it detecting 20 simultaneous touch points. I don't know if the surface itself (screen, not the "Surface" device) can detect/support more. Also,  3M's [M2256PW monitor](http://solutions.3m.com/wps/portal/3M/en_US/TouchSystems/TouchScreen/Solutions/Multitouch/M2256PW/) also supports up to 20 touch points.

If you install the [MultiTouchVista](http://multitouchvista.codeplex.com/) emulator driver, Windows does report it as having 255 touch points (mice), which may be a hard number set in the MTV code, and not Windows.

Basically, I would surmise that the number of points supported is likely higher than either

- The number of points the hardware can detect
- The total number of points you could fit on just about any hardware in regards to people around it

Comment: Do you have any information regarding what happens when Windows encounters too many touch points? Are the additional touch points just ignored or are they put in a sort of touch buffer to be processed after the current touches end?

Comment: From my experience, any extra points received are ignored. However, that hardware must be considered as far as handling points. Capacitive screens, such as phones and Surface tablets, 2-in-1 devices and laptops don't recognize the extra touches. However, devices that use systems such as an IR grid, such as the old HP TouchSmarts, will send up to the number of points it recognizes, but may get confused and send wildly incorrect touch data to the OS.